# Mysql Duplicate entry for primary key (AUTO_INCREMENT)

Tags: mysql, duplicates, primary-key

In my program, I insert record into table `tbl_name`. But I got a 'Duplicate entry for primary key' error, this makes me puzzle, Here is my code and errors.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_name` (
`id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'ID',
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'name',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=514 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='table'
```

Code:

```
public Integer batchInsert() {
    List<Object[]> updateList = Arrays.asList("name1","name2");

    if (updateList.size() > 0) {
        String insertSql = "insert into tbl_name (`name`) values (?)";
        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(insertSql, updateList);
    }
    return updateList.size();
}
```

Error:

```
17-11-18.00:26:00.262 [pool-5-thread-1] ERROR ApprovalService  - ERROR message: {"code":1,"message":"PreparedStatementCallback; SQL []; Duplicate entry '501' for key 'tbl_name_id'; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '501' for key 'tbl_name_id'","errorStackTraceMessage":null}
```

Answer (score 0):

Increment primary key column value to 502. It will start working.